# Why there's not homogeneous volume scatter in 2.72?

Tags: rendering, volumetrics, world

There was an option to render volume in blender 2.71. I was used to doing that like in this tutorial: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-atmospheric-lighting-blender/#.VKkh0CuG_h4

But now, in Blender 2.72, it is not possible to use homogeneous volume, because, the check button is just not there anymore!

[image]

I also tried to open project made in 2.72 in 2.71, and the option was there, but not in 2.72. Im really confused of that. Why is it removed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course this feature has **not** been removed; it's just moved in the UI.

You can now find it in the *Settings* subpanel of the *World* tab:

[image]

[image]